# How to make navbar responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive

I just learned about responsive design and adapting a page to smaller screens for accessibility, however, I'm having trouble thinking about a way to make my navbar responsive (showing the three bars instead of the whole navbar.

This is my custom navbar:

```css
:root{ --main_color: #004771; --main_color_shade: #072060; --footer_color: #383838;}

.navbar_maincontainer{width:100%; height:50px; background-color:var(--main_color); display:flex; align-items:center; padding:0px 100px; font-size:17px;}

.navbar_link_wrapper{width:auto; height:100%; position:relative; }

.navbar_link{color:white; font-size:17px; width:100%; height:100%; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; padding:0px 30px;}

.navbar_link_wrapper:hover{background-color:var(--main_color_shade);}

.navbar_sublinks_container{position:absolute; box-shadow:4px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); width:300px; height:auto; left:0px; top:-700px; transition:all 600ms ease; background-color:#383838; z-index:9999999999; display:none; flex-direction:column;}

.navbar_sublink{padding:0px 15px; height:50px; display:flex; align-items:center; transition:all 600ms ease; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8); font-size:14px; font-weight:400;}

.navbar_sublinks_line{width:100%; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1); height:1px; margin:0 auto;}

.navbar_sublinks_title{padding:10px 0px; width:100%; color:white; font-size:13px;}

.active{background-color:var(--main_color_shade);}

.active_sub{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}

.navbar_sublink:hover{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}

.navbar_link_wrapper:hover .navbar_sublinks_container{display:flex;  top:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="navbar_maincontainer" style="">
    <div class="navbar_link_wrapper">
        <a class="navbar_link" href="/" style="" title="Página de inicio">Inicio</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar_link_wrapper" style="margin-left:auto;">
        <a class="navbar_link" href="/clases" style="" title="Nuestros paquetes de adiestramiento canino en Málaga">Servicios</a>
        <div class="navbar_sublinks_container" style=" ">
            <a class="navbar_sublink" href="/clases/domicilio" style="">Clases a domicilio</a>
            <a class="navbar_sublink @if($pageInfo['submenu_active']=='Clases en grupo')active_sub @endif" href="/clases/grupo" style="">Clases en grupo</a>
            <a class="navbar_sublink" href="/clases/cachorros" style="">Clases para cachorros</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar_link_wrapper" style="">
        <a class="navbar_link" href="/quienes-somos" style="" title="Conoce al grupo Costadog">Quienes somos</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar_link_wrapper">
        <a class="navbar_link" href="/formate-con-nosotros" title="Conviertete en adiestrador canino">Formate con nosotros</a>
        <div class="navbar_sublinks_container">
            <a class="navbar_sublink" href="/formate-con-nosotros/formacion-basica">Formación básica</a>
            <a class="navbar_sublink" href="/formate-con-nosotros/formacion-avanzada">Formación avanzada</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar_link_wrapper">
        <a class="navbar_link" href="/contactar" style="" title="Ponte en contacto con nuestros entrenadores expertos">Contactar</a>
        
    </div>
    <div class="navbar_link_wrapper">
        <a class="navbar_link" href="/testimonios-de-nuestros-clientes" title="Testimonios de nuestros clientes">Testimonios</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar_link_wrapper">
        <a class="navbar_link" href="/preguntas-y-respuestas" title="Preguntas y respuestas frecuentes">Preguntas</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to code it yourself, you should use so called `CSS Media Queries`, which is well documented over at [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Answer (score 0):

> **Add** `max-width:100vw`(*vw is viewport width*) to `.navbar_maincontainer`
>
> **Remove** `width:100%` from `.navbar_link`

```css
:root {
  --main_color: #004771;
  --main_color_shade: #072060;
  --footer_color: #383838;
}

.navbar_maincontainer {
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: var(--main_color);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 100px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar_link_wrapper {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar_link {
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 30px;
}

.navbar_link_wrapper:hover {
  background-color: var(--main_color_shade);
}

.navbar_sublinks_container {
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  left: 0px;
  top: -700px;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
  background-color: #383838;
  z-index: 9999999999;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.navbar_sublink {
  padding: 0px 15px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.navbar_sublinks_line {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar_sublinks_title {
  padding: 10px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.active {
  background-color: var(--main_color_shade);
}

.active_sub {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.navbar_sublink:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.navbar_link_wrapper:hover .navbar_sublinks_container {
  display: flex;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar_maincontainer" style="">
  <div class="navbar_link_wrapper">
    <a class="navbar_link" href="/" style="" title="Página de inicio">Inicio</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar_link_wrapper" style="margin-left:auto;">
    <a class="navbar_link" href="/clases" style="" title="Nuestros paquetes de adiestramiento canino en Málaga">Servicios</a>
    <div class="navbar_sublinks_container" style=" ">
      <a class="navbar_sublink" href="/clases/domicilio" style="">Clases a domicilio</a>
      <a class="navbar_sublink @if($pageInfo['submenu_active']=='Clases en grupo')active_sub @endif" href="/clases/grupo" style="">Clases en grupo</a>
      <a class="navbar_sublink" href="/clases/cachorros" style="">Clases para cachorros</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar_link_wrapper" style="">
      <a class="navbar_link" href="/quienes-somos" style="" title="Conoce al grupo Costadog">Quienes somos</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar_link_wrapper">
      <a class="navbar_link" href="/formate-con-nosotros" title="Conviertete en adiestrador canino">Formate con nosotros</a>
      <div class="navbar_sublinks_container">
        <a class="navbar_sublink" href="/formate-con-nosotros/formacion-basica">Formación básica</a>
        <a class="navbar_sublink" href="/formate-con-nosotros/formacion-avanzada">Formación avanzada</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar_link_wrapper">
      <a class="navbar_link" href="/contactar" style="" title="Ponte en contacto con nuestros entrenadores expertos">Contactar</a>

    </div>
    <div class="navbar_link_wrapper">
      <a class="navbar_link" href="/testimonios-de-nuestros-clientes" title="Testimonios de nuestros clientes">Testimonios</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar_link_wrapper">
      <a class="navbar_link" href="/preguntas-y-respuestas" title="Preguntas y respuestas frecuentes">Preguntas</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const selectElement =(element)=>document.querySelector(element);
   selectElement('.mobile-menu').addeEventListner('click',()=>{
     selectElement('header').classList.toggle('active');
   })
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: "SF Pro Display", sans-serif;
}
a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
.container {
  max-width: 98rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 2.2rem;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1400;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4.4rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2rem);
}

.nav-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 -1rem;
}

.nav-list-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.nav-link-apple {
  width: 1.6rem;
  height: 4.4rem;
  background: url("/assets/apple.svg") center no-repeat;
}

.nav-link-search {
  width: 1.6rem;
  height: 4.4rem;
  background: url("/assets/search.svg") center no-repeat;
}
.nav-link-bag {
  width: 1.4rem;
  height: 4.4rem;
  background: url("/assets/bag.svg") center no-repeat;
}

.iphone-11-pro {
  background: url("/assets/iphone_11_pro_large.jpg");
  margin-top: 4.4rem;
}

.hero {
  height: 69.2rem;
  background-size: auto 73.6rem;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-top: 0.6rem solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 0.6rem solid #fff;
}

.title {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5.5rem;
}

.title-heading {
  font-size: 5.6rem;
  line-height: 1.07143;
  letter-spacing: -0.005rem;
}

.title-sub-heading {
  font-size: 2.65rem;
  margin-top: 0.6rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.008rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.title-price {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  color: #888;
  margin-top: 0.68rem;
}

.cta {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1.8rem;
}
.cta-link {
  color: #66bbff;
  font-size: 2.1rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cta-link:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 2.6rem;
}

.cta-link:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #66bbff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1068px) {
  .iphone-11-pro {
    background: url("/assets/iphone_11_pro_medium.jpg");
  }
  .hero {
    height: 65rem;
    background-size: auto 69.8rem;
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    // border-top: .6rem solid #fff;
    // border-bottom: .6rem solid #fff ;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .header {
    height: 4.8rem;
    transition: background 0.36s cubic-bezier(0.32, 0.68, 0.24, 1),
      height 0.56s cubic-bezier(0.32, 0.68, 0.24, 1);
  }

  .header .container {
    padding: 0;
  }

  .nav-list {
    margin-top: 0;
  }

  .nav-item {
    width: 4.8rem;
    height: 4.8rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .nav-item-hidden {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-menu {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1500;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .line {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1.7rem;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: margin-top 0.3192s cubic-bezier(0.04, 0.04, 0.12, 0.96);
  }

  .line-top {
    margin-top: 3px;
  }
  .line-bottom {
    margin-top: -0.4rem;
  }
  .active .line-top {
    margin-top: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: transform 0.3192s 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.04, 0.04, 0.12, 0.96);
  }
  .active .line-bottom {
    margin-top: 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition: transform 0.3192s 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.04, 0.04, 0.12, 0.96);
  }

  .header.active {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
  }
  .nav-link-apple {
    width: 1.8rem;
    height: 4.8rem;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1500;

    //
  }
  .nav-link-bag {
    width: 1.8rem;
    height: 4.8rem;
    transition: opacity 3s;
  }

  .nav {
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav-link {
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
  }

  .nav-list-larger {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 10.5rem;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
  }

  .nav-list-mobile {
    display: flex;
  }

  .active .nav-list-larger {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .active .nav-list-bag {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity;
  }
  .nav-list-larger .nav-item {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  .nav-list-larger .nav-item:nth-child(9) {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .active .nav-list-larger .nav-item {
    animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in;
  }
  @keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul class="nav-list nav-list-mobile">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <div class="mobile-menu">
                        <span class="line line-top"></span>
                        <span class="line line-bottom"></span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="index.html" class="nav-link nav-link-apple"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link-bag"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav-list nav-list-larger">
    
                <li class="nav-item nav-item-hidden">
                    <a href="index.html" class="nav-link nav-link-apple">
                       <!-- <i class="fa fa-apple"></i> -->
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Mac</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">iPad</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">iPhone</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Watch</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">TV</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Music</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Support</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link-search"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item nav-item-hidden">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-link-bag"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="nav-container">
  <nav>
    <ul class="mobile-nav">
      <li>
        <div class="menu-icon-container">
          <div class="menu-icon">
            <span class="line-1"></span>
            <span class="line-2"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="link-logo"></a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="" class="link-bag"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="desktop-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="link-logo"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Mac</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">iPad</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">iPhone</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Watch</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">TV</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Music</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Support</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="link-search"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="link-bag"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!-- End of navigation menu items -->

  <div class="search-container hide">
    <div class="link-search"></div>
    <div class="search-bar">
      <form action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search apple.com" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="link-close"></div>

    <div class="quick-links">
      <h2>Quick Links</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Visiting an Apple Store FAQ</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Shop Apple Store Online</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Accessories</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">AirPods</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">AirTag</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mobile-search-container">
    <div class="link-search"></div>
    <div class="search-bar">
      <form action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search apple.com" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <span class="cancel-btn">Cancel</span>

    <div class="quick-links">
      <h2>Quick Links</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Visiting an Apple Store FAQ</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Shop Apple Store Online</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Accessories</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">AirPods</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">AirTag</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>



    const searchButton = document.querySelector("nav .desktop-nav .link-search");
    const closeButton = document.querySelector(".search-container .link-close");
    const desktopNav = document.querySelector(".desktop-nav");
    const searchContainer = document.querySelector(".search-container");
    const overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay");

    searchButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        desktopNav.classList.add("hide");
        searchContainer.classList.remove("hide");
        overlay.classList.add("show");
    })

    closeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        desktopNav.classList.remove("hide");
        searchContainer.classList.add("hide");
        overlay.classList.remove("show");
    })

    overlay.addEventListener("click", () => {
        desktopNav.classList.remove("hide");
        searchContainer.classList.add("hide");
        overlay.classList.remove("show");
    })


    // Mobile Version

    const menuIconContainer = document.querySelector("nav .menu-icon-container");
    const navContainer = document.querySelector(".nav-container");

    menuIconContainer.addEventListener("click", () => {
        navContainer.classList.toggle("active");
    })


    const searchBar = document.querySelector(".mobile-search-container .search-bar");
    const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-container nav");
    const searchInput = document.querySelector(".mobile-search-container input");
    const cancelBtn = document.querySelector(".mobile-search-container .cancel-btn");

    searchInput.addEventListener("click", () => {
        searchBar.classList.add("active");
        nav.classList.add("move-up");
        desktopNav.classList.add("move-down");
    })

    cancelBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        searchBar.classList.remove("active");
        nav.classList.remove("move-up");
        desktopNav.classList.remove("move-down");
    })
    *,
    *::after,
    *::before {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    /* Desktop Nav */

    .nav-container {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        height: 44px;
        z-index: 300;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    .nav-container nav {
        width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 8px;
        height: 100%;
    }

    nav .desktop-nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        list-style: none;
    }

    nav .desktop-nav li a {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 14px;
        opacity: 0.8;
        transition: opacity 400ms;
    }

    nav .desktop-nav li a:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .link-logo {
        background: url('images/apple-logo.svg');
        display: block;
        background-position: center;
        height: 44px;
        width: 15px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .link-search {
        background: url('images/search-icon.svg');
        display: block;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 18px;
        height: 44px;
        width: 20px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .link-bag {
        background: url('images/bag-icon.svg');
        display: block;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 17px;
        height: 44px;
        width: 20px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .link-close {
        background: url('images/close-icon.svg');
        display: block;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 17px;
        height: 44px;
        width: 20px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    /* Search Container */

    .search-container.hide {
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .search-container {
        width: 60%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 42px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 200;
    }

    .search-container .link-search {
        position: absolute;
        left: 12px;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .search-container .link-close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 12px;
        opacity: 0.5;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 400ms;
    }

    .search-container .link-close:hover {
        opacity: 0.7;
    }

    .search-container form {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .search-container form input {
        width: 100%;
        height: 44px;
        border: 0;
        outline: none;
        background: transparent;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
        font-size: 17px;
    }

    /* Overlay */

    .overlay.show {
        position: fixed;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    /* Quick Links */

    .search-container .quick-links {
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding: 16px 8px;
        border-radius: 0 0 16px 16px;
    }

    .search-container .quick-links h2 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #6e6e73;
        margin: 0 32px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .search-container .quick-links ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin-top: 12px;
    }

    .search-container .quick-links ul li a {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 8px 50px;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #1d1d1f;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    .search-container .quick-links ul li a:hover {
        background: #f5f5f5;
        color: #2997ff;
    }

    /* Desktop Nav Animation */

    .desktop-nav li {
        transition: all 400ms ease;
    }

    .desktop-nav.hide li {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0.8);
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    /* Overlay Animation */

    .overlay {
        transition: all 400ms ease;
    }

    /* Navigation Menu Items Transition Delay */

    .desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(1),
    .desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(10) {
        transition-delay: 0ms;
    }

    .desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(2),
    .desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(9) {
        transition-delay: 30ms;
    }

    .desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(3),
    .desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(8) {
        transition-delay: 60ms;
    }

    .desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(4),
    .desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(7) {
        transition-delay: 90ms;
    }

    .desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(5),
    .desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(6) {
        transition-delay: 120ms;
    }

    .desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(6),
    .desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(5) {
        transition-delay: 150ms;
    }

    .desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(7),
    .desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(4) {
        transition-delay: 180ms;
    }

    .desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(8),
    .desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(3) {
        transition-delay: 210ms;
    }

    .desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(9),
    .desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(2) {
        transition-delay: 240ms;
    }

    .desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(10),
    .desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(1) {
        transition-delay: 270ms;
    }

    /* Search Container Animation */

    .search-container form,
    .search-container .link-search {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
        transition: all 400ms ease;
        transition-delay: 300ms;
    }

    .search-container.hide form,
    .search-container.hide .link-search {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }

    .search-container .link-search {
        opacity: 0.6;
    }

    .search-container.hide .link-close {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .search-container .link-close {
        opacity: 0.5;
        transition: all 400ms ease;
        transition-delay: 400ms;
    }

    .search-container.hide .quick-links h2 {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }

    .search-container .quick-links h2 {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
        transition: all 400ms ease;
        transition-delay: 100ms;
    }

    .search-container.hide .quick-links ul li {
        transform: translateX(60px);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .search-container .quick-links ul li {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
        transition: all 400ms ease;
    }

    .search-container .quick-links ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
        transition-delay: 120ms;
    } 

    .search-container .quick-links ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
        transition-delay: 140ms;
    } 

    .search-container .quick-links ul li:nth-of-type(3) {
        transition-delay: 160ms;
    } 

    .search-container .quick-links ul li:nth-of-type(4) {
        transition-delay: 180ms;
    } 

    .search-container .quick-links ul li:nth-of-type(5) {
        transition-delay: 200ms;
    } 


    /* Hidden Items */

    .mobile-nav,
    .mobile-search-container {
        display: none;
    }


    /* Media Queries */

    @media (max-width: 1100px) {
        .nav-container nav {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0 32px;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .nav-container .desktop-nav {
            flex-direction: column;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 0vh;
            background: #000;
            justify-content: start;
            overflow: hidden;
            z-index: -1;
            transition: all 1000ms ease;
        }

        .nav-container.active .desktop-nav {
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .nav-container .desktop-nav li {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0 32px;
        }

        .nav-container .desktop-nav li:first-child {
            margin-top: 120px;
        }

        .nav-container .desktop-nav .link-logo,
        .nav-container .desktop-nav .link-search,
        .nav-container .desktop-nav .link-bag {
            display: none;
        }

        .nav-container .desktop-nav li a {
            padding: 16px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #616161;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 17px;
            transform: translateY(-80px);
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 700ms ease;
        }

        .nav-container.active .desktop-nav li a {
            transform: translateY(0);
            opacity: 1;
        }

        /* Mobile Nav */

        nav .mobile-nav {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            justify-content: space-between;
            list-style: none;
        }

        nav .menu-icon-container {
            width: 20px;
            height: 44px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        nav .menu-icon {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }

        nav .menu-icon .line-1,
        nav .menu-icon .line-2 {
            position: absolute;
            height: 1px;
            width: 100%;
            background: #fff;
            transition-property: transform, top;
            transition-delay: 0ms, 160ms;
            transition-duration: 200ms;
        }

        nav .menu-icon .line-1 {
            top: -4px;
        }

        nav .menu-icon .line-2 {
            top: 4px;
        }

        .nav-container.active nav .menu-icon-container .menu-icon .line-1 {
            top: 0;
            transform: rotateZ(45deg);
            transition-property: top, transform;
            transition-delay: 0ms, 160ms;
            transition-duration: 200ms;
        }

        .nav-container.active nav .menu-icon-container .menu-icon .line-2 {
            top: 0;
            transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
            transition-property: top, transform;
            transition-delay: 0ms, 160ms;
            transition-duration: 200ms;
        }

        /* Bag Icon Animation */

        .nav-container.active .mobile-nav .link-bag {
            transform: translateY(8px);
            opacity: 0;
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        .nav-container .mobile-nav .link-bag {
            transition: all 1000ms ease;
        }



        /* Search Box */

        .mobile-search-container input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 12px 36px;
            font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
            font-size: 17px;
            background: #1b1b1b;
            border: 0;
            color: #fff;
            border-radius: 8px;
            outline: none;
        }

        .mobile-search-container {
            position: relative;
            padding: 0 16px;
            margin-top: -30px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #616161;
            display: flex;
            padding-bottom: 16px;
            align-items: center;
            transform: rotateX(90deg);
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 600ms ease;
        }

        .nav-container.active .mobile-search-container {
            transform: rotateX(0deg);
            margin-top: 10px;
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .mobile-search-container .link-search {
            position: absolute;
            left: 24px;
            opacity: .5;
            background-size: 15px;
        }

        /* Nav Move Up */

        .nav-container nav.move-up {
            margin-top: -40px;
        }

        /* Cancel Button */

        .mobile-search-container .cancel-btn {
            color: #2997ff;
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: 400;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: all 400ms ease;
        }

        .mobile-search-container .search-bar.active + .cancel-btn {
            padding: 0 16px;
            width: 74px;
        }

        .mobile-search-container .search-bar {
            flex: 1;
        }

        /* Desktop Nav Move Down */

        nav .desktop-nav.move-down li:first-child {
            margin-top: 150px;
        }

        nav .desktop-nav.move-down li {
            opacity: 0;
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        
        /* Quick Links */

        .mobile-search-container .search-bar.active ~ .quick-links {
            top: 80px;
            opacity: 1;
            pointer-events: auto;
            transition-delay: 40ms;
        }

        .mobile-search-container .quick-links {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            padding: 0 32px;
            opacity: 0;
            pointer-events: none;
            top: 10px;
            transition: all 400ms ease;
        }

        .mobile-search-container .quick-links ul {
            list-style: none;
        }

        .mobile-search-container .quick-links h2 {
            color: #86868b;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: 400;
        }

        .mobile-search-container .quick-links ul li a {
            padding: 16px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 400;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #616161;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .mobile-search-container .quick-links ul li a:hover {
            color: #2997ff;
        }

        /* Nav Animation */

        .nav-container nav {
            transition: all 400ms ease;
        }
    }


    input,
    div,
    span,
    a {
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Apple</title>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="nav-container">
            <nav>
                <ul class="mobile-nav">
                    <li>
                        <div class="menu-icon-container">
                            <div class="menu-icon">
                                <span class="line-1"></span>
                                <span class="line-2"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="link-logo"></a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="link-bag"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="desktop-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="link-logo"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Mac</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">iPad</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">iPhone</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Watch</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">TV</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Music</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Support</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="link-search"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="link-bag"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <!-- End of navigation menu items -->

            <div class="search-container hide">
                <div class="link-search"></div>
                <div class="search-bar">
                    <form action="">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search apple.com">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="link-close"></div>

                <div class="quick-links">
                    <h2>Quick Links</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Visiting an Apple Store FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Shop Apple Store Online</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Accessories</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">AirPods</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">AirTag</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="mobile-search-container">
                <div class="link-search"></div>
                <div class="search-bar">
                    <form action="">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search apple.com">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <span class="cancel-btn">Cancel</span>

                <div class="quick-links">
                    <h2>Quick Links</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Visiting an Apple Store FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Shop Apple Store Online</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Accessories</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">AirPods</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">AirTag</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            

        </div>


        <div class="overlay"></div>
        
        <script src="main.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const searchButton = document.querySelector("nav .desktop-nav .link-search");
const closeButton = document.querySelector(".search-container .link-close");
const desktopNav = document.querySelector(".desktop-nav");
const searchContainer = document.querySelector(".search-container");
const overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay");

searchButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    desktopNav.classList.add("hide");
    searchContainer.classList.remove("hide");
    overlay.classList.add("show");
})

closeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    desktopNav.classList.remove("hide");
    searchContainer.classList.add("hide");
    overlay.classList.remove("show");
})

overlay.addEventListener("click", () => {
    desktopNav.classList.remove("hide");
    searchContainer.classList.add("hide");
    overlay.classList.remove("show");
})


// Mobile Version

const menuIconContainer = document.querySelector("nav .menu-icon-container");
const navContainer = document.querySelector(".nav-container");

menuIconContainer.addEventListener("click", () => {
    navContainer.classList.toggle("active");
})


const searchBar = document.querySelector(".mobile-search-container .search-bar");
const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-container nav");
const searchInput = document.querySelector(".mobile-search-container input");
const cancelBtn = document.querySelector(".mobile-search-container .cancel-btn");

searchInput.addEventListener("click", () => {
    searchBar.classList.add("active");
    nav.classList.add("move-up");
    desktopNav.classList.add("move-down");
})

cancelBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    searchBar.classList.remove("active");
    nav.classList.remove("move-up");
    desktopNav.classList.remove("move-down");
})
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* Desktop Nav */

.nav-container {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 44px;
    z-index: 300;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.nav-container nav {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 8px;
    height: 100%;
}

nav .desktop-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
}

nav .desktop-nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: opacity 400ms;
}

nav .desktop-nav li a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.link-logo {
    background: url('images/apple-logo.svg');
    display: block;
    background-position: center;
    height: 44px;
    width: 15px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.link-search {
    background: url('images/search-icon.svg');
    display: block;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 18px;
    height: 44px;
    width: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.link-bag {
    background: url('images/bag-icon.svg');
    display: block;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 17px;
    height: 44px;
    width: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.link-close {
    background: url('images/close-icon.svg');
    display: block;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 17px;
    height: 44px;
    width: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Search Container */

.search-container.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.search-container {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 42px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 200;
}

.search-container .link-search {
    position: absolute;
    left: 12px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.search-container .link-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 12px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 400ms;
}

.search-container .link-close:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.search-container form {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.search-container form input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Overlay */

.overlay.show {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}

/* Quick Links */

.search-container .quick-links {
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 16px 8px;
    border-radius: 0 0 16px 16px;
}

.search-container .quick-links h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #6e6e73;
    margin: 0 32px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.search-container .quick-links ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.search-container .quick-links ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 50px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #1d1d1f;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.search-container .quick-links ul li a:hover {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    color: #2997ff;
}

/* Desktop Nav Animation */

.desktop-nav li {
    transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.desktop-nav.hide li {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.8);
    pointer-events: none;
}

/* Overlay Animation */

.overlay {
    transition: all 400ms ease;
}

/* Navigation Menu Items Transition Delay */

.desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(1),
.desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(10) {
    transition-delay: 0ms;
}

.desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(2),
.desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(9) {
    transition-delay: 30ms;
}

.desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(3),
.desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(8) {
    transition-delay: 60ms;
}

.desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(4),
.desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(7) {
    transition-delay: 90ms;
}

.desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(5),
.desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(6) {
    transition-delay: 120ms;
}

.desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(6),
.desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(5) {
    transition-delay: 150ms;
}

.desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(7),
.desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(4) {
    transition-delay: 180ms;
}

.desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(8),
.desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(3) {
    transition-delay: 210ms;
}

.desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(9),
.desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(2) {
    transition-delay: 240ms;
}

.desktop-nav li:nth-of-type(10),
.desktop-nav.hide li:nth-of-type(1) {
    transition-delay: 270ms;
}

/* Search Container Animation */

.search-container form,
.search-container .link-search {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.search-container.hide form,
.search-container.hide .link-search {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
}

.search-container .link-search {
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.search-container.hide .link-close {
    opacity: 0;
}

.search-container .link-close {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    transition-delay: 400ms;
}

.search-container.hide .quick-links h2 {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
}

.search-container .quick-links h2 {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    transition-delay: 100ms;
}

.search-container.hide .quick-links ul li {
    transform: translateX(60px);
    opacity: 0;
}

.search-container .quick-links ul li {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.search-container .quick-links ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
    transition-delay: 120ms;
} 

.search-container .quick-links ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
    transition-delay: 140ms;
} 

.search-container .quick-links ul li:nth-of-type(3) {
    transition-delay: 160ms;
} 

.search-container .quick-links ul li:nth-of-type(4) {
    transition-delay: 180ms;
} 

.search-container .quick-links ul li:nth-of-type(5) {
    transition-delay: 200ms;
} 


/* Hidden Items */

.mobile-nav,
.mobile-search-container {
    display: none;
}


/* Media Queries */

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
    .nav-container nav {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 32px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-container .desktop-nav {
        flex-direction: column;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0vh;
        background: #000;
        justify-content: start;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: -1;
        transition: all 1000ms ease;
    }

    .nav-container.active .desktop-nav {
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .nav-container .desktop-nav li {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 32px;
    }

    .nav-container .desktop-nav li:first-child {
        margin-top: 120px;
    }

    .nav-container .desktop-nav .link-logo,
    .nav-container .desktop-nav .link-search,
    .nav-container .desktop-nav .link-bag {
        display: none;
    }

    .nav-container .desktop-nav li a {
        padding: 16px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #616161;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 17px;
        transform: translateY(-80px);
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 700ms ease;
    }

    .nav-container.active .desktop-nav li a {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    /* Mobile Nav */

    nav .mobile-nav {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-between;
        list-style: none;
    }

    nav .menu-icon-container {
        width: 20px;
        height: 44px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    nav .menu-icon {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

    nav .menu-icon .line-1,
    nav .menu-icon .line-2 {
        position: absolute;
        height: 1px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #fff;
        transition-property: transform, top;
        transition-delay: 0ms, 160ms;
        transition-duration: 200ms;
    }

    nav .menu-icon .line-1 {
        top: -4px;
    }

    nav .menu-icon .line-2 {
        top: 4px;
    }

    .nav-container.active nav .menu-icon-container .menu-icon .line-1 {
        top: 0;
        transform: rotateZ(45deg);
        transition-property: top, transform;
        transition-delay: 0ms, 160ms;
        transition-duration: 200ms;
    }

    .nav-container.active nav .menu-icon-container .menu-icon .line-2 {
        top: 0;
        transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
        transition-property: top, transform;
        transition-delay: 0ms, 160ms;
        transition-duration: 200ms;
    }

    /* Bag Icon Animation */

    .nav-container.active .mobile-nav .link-bag {
        transform: translateY(8px);
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .nav-container .mobile-nav .link-bag {
        transition: all 1000ms ease;
    }



    /* Search Box */

    .mobile-search-container input {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px 36px;
        font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
        font-size: 17px;
        background: #1b1b1b;
        border: 0;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 8px;
        outline: none;
    }

    .mobile-search-container {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 16px;
        margin-top: -30px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #616161;
        display: flex;
        padding-bottom: 16px;
        align-items: center;
        transform: rotateX(90deg);
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 600ms ease;
    }

    .nav-container.active .mobile-search-container {
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
        margin-top: 10px;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .mobile-search-container .link-search {
        position: absolute;
        left: 24px;
        opacity: .5;
        background-size: 15px;
    }

    /* Nav Move Up */

    .nav-container nav.move-up {
        margin-top: -40px;
    }

    /* Cancel Button */

    .mobile-search-container .cancel-btn {
        color: #2997ff;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 400;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: all 400ms ease;
    }

    .mobile-search-container .search-bar.active + .cancel-btn {
        padding: 0 16px;
        width: 74px;
    }

    .mobile-search-container .search-bar {
        flex: 1;
    }

    /* Desktop Nav Move Down */

    nav .desktop-nav.move-down li:first-child {
        margin-top: 150px;
    }

    nav .desktop-nav.move-down li {
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    
    /* Quick Links */

    .mobile-search-container .search-bar.active ~ .quick-links {
        top: 80px;
        opacity: 1;
        pointer-events: auto;
        transition-delay: 40ms;
    }

    .mobile-search-container .quick-links {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding: 0 32px;
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        top: 10px;
        transition: all 400ms ease;
    }

    .mobile-search-container .quick-links ul {
        list-style: none;
    }

    .mobile-search-container .quick-links h2 {
        color: #86868b;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    .mobile-search-container .quick-links ul li a {
        padding: 16px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 400;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #616161;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .mobile-search-container .quick-links ul li a:hover {
        color: #2997ff;
    }

    /* Nav Animation */

    .nav-container nav {
        transition: all 400ms ease;
    }
}


input,
div,
span,
a {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
    <div class="nav-container">
        <nav>
            <ul class="mobile-nav">
                <li>
                    <div class="menu-icon-container">
                        <div class="menu-icon">
                            <span class="line-1"></span>
                            <span class="line-2"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="link-logo"></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="" class="link-bag"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="desktop-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="link-logo"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Mac</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">iPad</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">iPhone</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Watch</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">TV</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Music</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Support</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="link-search"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="link-bag"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <!-- End of navigation menu items -->

        <div class="search-container hide">
            <div class="link-search"></div>
            <div class="search-bar">
                <form action="">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search apple.com">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="link-close"></div>

            <div class="quick-links">
                <h2>Quick Links</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Visiting an Apple Store FAQ</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Shop Apple Store Online</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Accessories</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">AirPods</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">AirTag</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="mobile-search-container">
            <div class="link-search"></div>
            <div class="search-bar">
                <form action="">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search apple.com">
                </form>
            </div>
            <span class="cancel-btn">Cancel</span>

            <div class="quick-links">
                <h2>Quick Links</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Visiting an Apple Store FAQ</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Shop Apple Store Online</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Accessories</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">AirPods</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">AirTag</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        

    </div>


    <div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to explain what you change and why this should fix the answer ?